# Kotlin issue when trying to cast "attachBadgeDrawable": This declaration is opt-in

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, material-components-android, android-annotations

I would use the `BadgeDrawable` in my Android app on a `Button`, the issue is that when i'm trying to set to the button layout the `badgeDrawable` via `attachBadgeDrawable` i get an error on it which says:

```
his declaration is opt-in and its usage should be marked with  '@com.google.android.material.badge.ExperimentalBadgeUtils' or '@OptIn(markerClass = com.google.android.material.badge.ExperimentalBadgeUtils.class)'
```

The code where i use that piece of code is the following:

```
            btnInvia.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                        val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(requireContext())
                        badgeDrawable.number = corpo
                        badgeDrawable.verticalOffset = 20
                        badgeDrawable.horizontalOffset = 15
                        BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, btnInvia, layoutInvia)
                        btnInvia.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    }

                }
            )
```

if it could be usefull the min SDK is 24.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class `BadgeUtils` is marked with the androidx annotation [`@Experimental`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/experimental/Experimental). In this way it is reported the usages of experimental API in this case with a level = `ERROR`.

In your method you have to use one of these annotations to suppress the report:

```
@ExperimentalBadgeUtils
@UseExperimental(markerClass = ExperimentalBadgeUtils::class)
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
   btnInvia.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
      //..
   )
}
```

You can also use the kotlin annotation `@OptIn`:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalBadgeUtils::class)
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //...
       btnInvia.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
          //..
       )
}
```